# Could not locate deviceQuery on my installation Cuda toolkit v7.5 on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, matlab, cuda

As I was going through installing Cuda v7.5 following this link http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#compiling-examples

I was not able to verify the installation as described in section 2.5. Verify the Installation. The reason was because I could not find deviceQuery program that should have been located in

```
C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v7.5\bin\win64\Release
```

Therefore, I could not run the deviceQuery for Cuda to be verified. Where is deviceQuery program located ? Is it still precompiled and deployed by the installation ?

Answer (score 5):

Okay, so if you are a complete noob like me in using Visual Studio then you might be thrown off by the instruction "build the application first". Just watch this video to get an idea of how to build and run a project/program using VS.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cL05xtTocmY

As soon as you open VS (I am using 15.6), you will be prompted to upgrade the SDK. Make sure to do so. If you've misclicked or skipped upgrading, you can go to the Project pull down menu and click "Retarget Solution" and click ok on the menu that appears. Then build and debug as shown in the video.

Creating the deviceQuery.exe file:

Go to the (default) directory C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDA Samples\v9.2\1_Utilities\deviceQuery. Just follow the procedure of running the MatMul file but this time build the deviceQuery_vs2017.sln file and debug it. Remember to retarget the solution.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not precompiled any more.

You have to compile (build) the application first, before you can run it.

That is true for all the CUDA samples now.

Comment: May you please tell me more about what you are mentioning I am completely new to this stuff. Is there a reference or anything you recommend for beginners? Thank you in advance

Comment: The `deviceQuery` program (and all CUDA samples) must be built from source code before they can be used.  The method to do this is described in [section 3 of the installation guide you linked](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-microsoft-windows/#compiling-cuda-programs)

Answer (score 3):

OK, I've had this problem with CUDA Toolkit 10 under Windows 10. In my case, I do never use the admin account, and the installation was done from the user account, entering the admin password when necessary. After repeated trials, here's what worked for me:

1. Make sure to uninstall any old version of CUDA and Visual Studio
   (just to have a clean start)
2. Restart the computer
3. Install Microsoft Visual Studio Community Edition. During the
   install, make sure to select the C++ Development tools
4. Restart
5. Install the Cuda Toolkit
6. Restart

With this, I had all the files. But the deviceQuery still would not compile because it was targeted to an older version of Windows. To compile it, one needs to 'Retarget' the project to the current windows SDK. However, this doesn't work out-of-the-box because the 'deviceQuery_vs2017.vcxproj' file is read-only for regular users.

So, there are two possible solutions:

1. Copy the folder to some place where you have write permission, or
2. *(This is what I used, for convenience)* Using Windows Explorer, navigate to the *`C:\ProgramData\NVIDIA Corporation`* directory. Right click on the 'CUDA Samples' directory, select 'Properties'. Under the 'Security' tab, click 'Edit' and add your user to it.

This way you can Retarget the solution in place. After that, I could open the solution in MS Visual Studio, Retarget it, build it and test it, and all worked fine.

Hope that helps.